# future simple with some words adding

Tags: sentence-meaning

Consider these two example sentences:

> I don't think Kelly will pass the exam.

and

> Kelly will not pass the exam.

Is it absolutely the same meaning or not if someone says these phrases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I don't think I understand" vs. "I don't understand"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/241051/i-dont-think-i-understand-vs-i-dont-understand)

Answer (score 1):

Saying the second one means you are sure that Kelly won’t pass. The first one is just you having a thought of her failing the test (based on some evidence).

But also focus on their pitch as well, pitches can change the meaning of phrases.

Ex: “I don’t think Kelly will pass the exam” said in a low and nervous voice pitch, means you are only having a thought or a fear that she might fail the test. But saying the same sentence with a high and confident pitch will make the listeners think that you already know Kelly is going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

No, Both the sentence are different. Your first sentence sounds to be a future prediction while the second sentence is your belief( i.e. you have proof for your statement )

Comment: You have got them backwards. "will" is a confident future prediction. "think" is used for a belief. A belief doesn't need any proof.